# searching results for li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i display based on searching text.i have one textbox. if i entered some word or letter i want to display matching li content.how can i do it? anyone help.

html:

```
  <input type="text" id="dropTextnew">
      <input type="button" name="team-btn" id="team-btn" value="Search">  
      <ul id="addList"> 
      <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>MacLeod Conner</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Dolores Arnold</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Blake Francis</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Chavarin Deanna</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Robert</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Zimmerman</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Zimmerman</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Chavarin Conner</span></li> 
      </ul>
```

JS:

```
 $("#team-btn").on("click", function(e){

 var textVal=$("#dropTextnew").val(); 

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/oqy1b9sy/

```
$("#team-btn").on("click", function(e){
 var textVal=$("#dropTextnew").val(); 
 var hits = 0;

 $("li").each(function() {
   if ($(this).text() == textVal) {
     $(this).css({color: "#f0f"})
     hits++;
   } else {
     $(this).css({opacity: 0.2})
   }
 })
 if (!hits) $("li").css({color: "#000"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
 hits = 0;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `:contains` selector.

```
$("#addList li").hide();
$("#addList li:contains('" + textVal "')").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to check if the li text contains the text in the search and hide the `li` which not contains.

```js
$("#team-btn").on("click", function(e) {
  var textVal = $("#dropTextnew").val();

  $('#addList li').show().filter(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('span').text());
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(textVal) == -1 && textVal != '';
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="dropTextnew">
<input type="button" name="team-btn" id="team-btn" value="Search">  
<ul id="addList"> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>MacLeod Conner</span></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Dolores Arnold</span></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Blake Francis</span></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Chavarin Deanna</span></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Robert</span></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Zimmerman</span></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Zimmerman</span></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Chavarin Conner</span></li> 
</ul>
```